# Finding default process scheduler

Tags: linux-kernel, process, scheduling

Where in the Linux code, I can find the default process scheduler at the time of launching a process. For a running process, `chrt` shows `SCHED_OTHER`. On the hand, in various websites, I see that the default scheduler is CFS. So, are these the same? I know `SCHED_OTHER` and `SCHED_NORMAL` are equal, but not sure about CFS.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completely fair scheduler is used for `SCHED_NORMAL` (aka `SCHED_OTHER`), `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE`. See [the kernel’s CFS documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.html) for details.

CFS is implemented in [`kernel/sched/fair.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/fair.c).